# R nls exponential curve

Tags: r, curve, exponential, exp

I have two vectors X and y2, and I wish to fit an exponential curve to the data.

I tried many approaches described on Stack Overflow topics but all of them give me just a straight line. e.g. I tried this:

```
model.three <- lm(log(y2) ~ log(X))
plot(X,predict(model.three))
abline(model.three)
```

My data:

```
X <- seq(1:50)
Y <- rnorm(50,mean=0,sd=1)
y2 <- exp(X)
y2 <- Y+y2
```

Comment: `log(y) ~ log(x)` will give a *power-law* fit to the data, not an exponential curve: did you want `log(y) ~ x`?  note, your main problem is with `abline()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
model.three <- lm(log(y2) ~ log(X))
plot(X,predict(model.three))

## Instead of abline(), use this:

lines(model.three$fitted.values)
```

Comment: I know this is old, but it is incorrect. You do not take the log of both variables, if you want an exponential best fit.

Answer (score 1):

Your data expresses an exponential relationship between Y and X, which is `Y = exp(X) + eps` where `eps` is some noise.
Therefore, I would suggest fitting a model between `log(Y)` and `X`, to capture the linear relationship between the two:

`model.three <- lm(log(y2) ~ X)
summary(model.three)`

The summary confirms that the relationship captured is as expected (i.e. the coefficient for X is very close to 1).

Since plotting the data on a linear scale will not be useful, I think it is a good idea to plot the fitted straight line with `abline`.

Note: to be exact, it would be more accurate to capture the relationship between y2 and exp(X), but with your data, the fit is essentially perfect.